# ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, winforms, executionengineexception

```
   private void CopyAllFilesToButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

        foreach (var item in files)
        {
                File.Copy(item, folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        }

    }
```

Basically, i have a number of file paths. I want to copy each one to a specific folder. What i did, i added folderBrowserDialog from the toolbox and put it inside a button event.

It throws that awkward exception when it reaches File.Copy..why is that, and how can i prevent it?

Comment: What is files? Are the paths correct? what is the error all these would be good things.

Comment: Could you supply the callstack of this `ExecutionEngineException`? This type of exception is not normally thrown from `File.Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying the file to copy to, which is where the exception is coming from.

You're doing `File.Copy(item,folderBrownserDialog1.SelectedPath);`, while you should be doing
`File.Copy(item,Path.Combine(folderBrownserDialog1.SelectedPath, item));`

That, of course, is if the list of `item` contains only the filenames, not the full current path to the file. If that's the case, you'll need to do something along these lines:

```
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            var fileName = new FileInfo(item);
            File.Copy(item, Path.Combine(folderBrownserDialog1.SelectedPath, fileName.Name));
        }
```

Comment: I tried your solution and i still gethtesame error,.. you provided the same methd with same parameters. But it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Here working solution:

```
private void buttonCopyFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
   string destDir = @"D:\dest";
   od.Multiselect = true;

   if (od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      foreach (var file in od.FileNames)
      {
         File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));
      }               
   }
}
```

Depending on selected files count and selected files size, your app may hang for a while